# Wildcard Matching Recursive Algorithm C++

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, recursion, wildcard

I have been writing a recursive wildcard matching algorithm in c++. But I'm having trouble completing it. Here look at what I write so far.

`?` matches any character, `*` matches any string

```
bool WildCardMatch(char *str, char *match){
 while (*match){
    if (*match =='?'){
        if (!*str){
            return false;
        }
        str++; 
        match++;
    }
    else if (*match == '*'){
        if (WildcardMatch(str, match + 1)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
 }
return !*str && !*match;
}
```

What's wrong with my algorithm? How should I fix it? Or can anyone suggest me a better solution for recursive wildcard matching algorithm?

Comment: What are the symptoms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/188256/A-Simple-Wildcard-Matching-Function) recursive wildcard matching algorithm. It will solve your troubles.

```
bool WildcardMatch(const TCHAR *pszString, const TCHAR *pszMatch){
while (*pszMatch)
{
    if (*pszMatch == _T('?'))
    {
        if (!*pszString)
            return false;

        ++pszString;
        ++pszMatch;
    }
    else if (*pszMatch == _T('*'))
    {
        if (WildcardMatch(pszString, pszMatch + 1))
            return true;

        if (*pszString && WildcardMatch(pszString + 1, pszMatch))
            return true;

        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (::CharUpper(MAKEINTRESOURCE(MAKELONG(*pszString++, 0))) != ::CharUpper(MAKEINTRESOURCE(MAKELONG(*pszMatch++, 0))))
            return false;
    }
}

return !*pszString && !*pszMatch;
}
```

Comment: whats the time complexity?

Comment: @user1846749 For strings without `*`, linear. For strings with `*`, exponential with regard to the number of asterisks. See the discussion for the "ABORT" modification from 1993 in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_wildcards#Examples_of_recursive_algorithms.

Comment: @user1846749 Alright, I've done porting the ABORT thing to this sample. See https://repl.it/repls/ScarceMinorTechnician.